# How to get the previous non 0 value from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I still have not read a simple solution to this problem.
This is the table that I have:

[image]

This is the result that I want:

[image]

Basically, if the value for column SeriesStartRowNum is 0, it should retrieve the lastest, previous non 0 value from the table.

Anyone that knows how to easily do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your title and question talk about different things; the title talks about `NULL` and  there are no `NULL` values in your data, where as the question about `0`. `0` and `NULL` are **completely** different values.

Comment: I don't really get your example. Shouldn't it be 1/4/4/4/4/4/4 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, due to images of data, but this looks like a gaps and island problem. One method, therefore, would be to use a windowed `COUNT` to count the number of non-zero values so far in the column `SeriesStartRowNum` to create "groups", and then in get the `MAX` value for `SeriesStartRowNum` in that group:

```sql
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT RowNumber,
           CustomerID,
           Value,
           StartDate,
           EndDate,
           SeriesStartRowNum,
           COUNT(NULLIF(SeriesStartRowNum,0)) OVER (/*PARTTION BY ???*/ ORDER BY RowNumber) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT RowNumber,
       CustomerID,
       Value,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       MAX(SeriesStartRowNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp)
FROM Groups;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your actual data is like the sample data that you posted, with the 1st row of each combination of `CustometID` and `Value` having a non-`0` value and all the rest are `0`s, then all you need is `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT RowNumber, CustometID, Value, StartDate, EndDate,
       MAX(SeriesStartRowNum) OVER (PARTITION BY CustometID, Value) SeriesStartRowNum
FROM tablename
```